# python is it considered bad practice to use global variables inside a class?

Tags: python, class, scope

In the code below, I access the global variable `n` inside a method in a class. If I intend on only reading the variable, is this considered bad practice? The alternative being passing the variable to a constructor or as an argument to `number`?

```
n = 2

class yes:

    def number(self):
        return n

y = yes()
print(y.number())
```

Comment: Global variables tend to be poor design in general. They're no better or worse in classes.

Comment: But classes also give you the opportunity to use class variables. If the global variable is only relevant to that class, you should do that instead.

Comment: If `n` is a global variable, why do you need a method that returns its value?

Comment: Also note: if the method does not use any attributes of the instance (`self`), it should probably be a `classmethod` (if it uses attributes of the class itself) or a `staticmethod` (if it uses no attributes of even the class, and is basically just a plain function that happens to be logically associated with the class and is included with it largely for namespacing purposes). So if `n` remains a global, `number` should be a `staticmethod`, while if it is moved to a class attribute as Barmar suggests (which is the sane way to do this), it should be a `classmethod`.

Comment: Global "constants" are OK, but the worst is mutable global state

Comment: @ShadowRanger you have enlightened me to the world of different class methods. This helps a ton, thanks!